# Bootstrap Tour Javascript only runs in modal when console is opened or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am using the Bootstrap Tour inside of a rails 4 app, using Chrome, everything works well until I need the tour to run inside of an existing modal.  I am using a .click() to access the modal but once inside it will not run the next step until you pop open the console or if the console is already open, then closing it resumes the tour, skipping one step.

From what I have been reading it could have been a console.log issue, but I have taken out all uses of the word console, with no result.

below is the JS file that runs, the bit that is inside the modal is the view_asset_steps module.

//VIEWING AN ASSET TOUR STEPS

```
var view_asset_steps = {
  onEnd: function() {
  $.cookie("current_tour", "undefined");
},
steps: [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: "#asset-tour-step-one",
    title: "Viewing an Asset",
    placement: "right",
    content: "Clicking anywhere on an asset will allow you to view that asset's details",
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: ".selected",
    title: "Viewing an Asset",
    placement: "right",
    content: "Clicking anywhere on an asset will allow you to view that asset's details",
     onNext: function(tour) {
     document.getElementById("view-asset-tour-modal-trigger").click();
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: ".visible",
    title:"Different Angles",
    placement: "right",
    content:"Different angles of the asset you chose will be displayed on the left",
   },
   {
    path: '/',
    element: "#view-asset-tour-right",
    title:"Other Details",
    placement: "left",
    content:"All other details will be displayed on the right",
   }
 ]};
```

//SET A COOKIE FOR EVERY TOUR

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     switch($.cookie("current_tour"))
    {
  case "focus":
    tour = new Tour(focus_steps).init();
    break;
  case "asset":
    tour = new Tour(asset_steps).init();
    break;
  case "view-asset":
    tour = new Tour(view_asset_steps).init();
    default:
  var tour = new Tour(asset_steps);
 }
});
```

//INITIALIZE VIEW-ASSET TOUR

```
 $(document).on("click", "#start-view-asset-tour", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    return;
  }
   tour = new Tour(view_asset_steps);
  $.cookie("current_tour", "view-asset");
   tour.init();
   tour.restart();

  return;
});
```

Comment: the problem here was, that the step was trying to load before the modal was on the page. so when it went to look for the step ID it was unavailable, I was able to solve this by putting  var stepOne = function() {
          tour.goTo(1)
        }
        window.setTimeout(stepOne, 1700);
      }
  }, before the offending step